# Typescript angular delay is set method

Tags: angular, typescript, concurrency

I have this method

```
 onDispositionChange(callStatus: ICallStatus): void {
    this.callStatus = callStatus;
    // this.form.setCallStatus(callStatus);
    this.form.onSubmit();
  }
```

But for some reason `this.form.onSubmit` gets called before `set callStatus(value: ICallStatus | undefined)`

```
@Input() set callStatus(value: ICallStatus | undefined) {
    console.log("Changing Status");
    this._callStatus = value;
    this.addConditionalValidation(this._callStatus);
  }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Please post complete code and not just fragments. What is setCallStatus?

Comment: Ther'e no problem with set method. I imagine you should call updateValueAndValidity, before call to this.form.onSubmit. If you change the validity of a form control called "control", some like `this.form.get('control').updateValueAndValidity()`. from the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#methods): "When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call updateValueAndValidity() for the new validation to take effect.": BTW I sugges you create a custom validator instead change the validator of a FormControl at run time